# Magento2.4.5: How to lazy load Jquery and remove unused scripts from Theme Desgin?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3, magento2.2, magento2.4

**I want to optimize my website and remove unused javascript/jquery and also defer or lazy load javascript/jquery for better performance
any tools or techniques to achieve this**?